# The country that became independent is no more

Tags: sentence, translation

**"The country that became independent is no more."**

*— Ahsanul Irfan*

I have translated this quote from Bangla language. Does the english version make sense?

What it means is that "The country has has become independent no longer exists".
This quote is an aphorism.

Comment: What do you mean by _no more_ in your sentence? Are you saying that the country doesn't "physically" exist anymore? Please making yourself clearer.

Comment: Online translators give "The country that has become independent is no more" or "The country that became independent is no more" hence I think that is okay.

Comment: @user405662 What I meant is that "The country that has become independent is no more a country, because it has become completely independent."  Does the english version means what I meant?

Comment: What you say you mean doesn't make sense. What is inconsistent between *country* and *independent*?  It would make more sense if *country* were *province* or *district*.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty And even then the province could still be said to exist because it's identifiable. AhsanulIrfan We need more than a literal translation; we need what the original actually means -- so for example, "is no more" may mean "no longer exists". Could *country* in your phrase be applied to something like "province" or "district"? As it is, an independent country certainly does exist, so it's difficult to see how the sentence actually makes sense.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yes, the original version actually means the country doesn't exist any more.

Comment: The language and the nationality English is always capitalised.

Comment: If the country doesn't exist anymore, what do you now call the area of dirt that the people live on?

Answer (score 1):

> "যে দেশ স্বাধীন হয়েছে সে দেশ আর নেই।" Ahsanul Irfan

The sense that this is trying to convey is

"The nature of the country that attained its independence (i.e. Bangladesh) is no longer the nature of the country that we now live in." i.e. the country has changed from the ideals it held and the spirit that it had when first independent.

If you are writing for a Bangladeshi audience, then "the country" = Bangladesh and the audience will recognise it. If what follows the quote clearly refers to Bangladesh, then the same will apply.

The quote, as it stands, requires context.

I suggest "The Bangladesh we knew at independence is no more."